# Chrome/Android kills websockets running in background

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-chrome, websocket

Google Chrome in android(also iPhone) kills websocket connections after some time that oscillates between 20seg - 3min, depending on device.
It also can't handle simple timers or intervals when application isn't in foreground, like in the example that I attach at bottom.

I understeand that this is normal, for update the lifetime of battery and preserve resources of mobile device,  but this sucks... It's a really pain for any web developer when users needs to be connected to socket all time, and not lose connection to websocket when simply open whatsapp to answer a message or other browser tab for something and then came back to webapp and its disconnected. For example, a chat room.

Is any workaround for this trouble? Something that can be configured directly from chrome, special permission for the webapp, some kind of bypass for this situation?
This is a webapp, added to start screen of android... and even so chrome doesnt seems to give it any particular priority and keeps killing websocket and refuses to execute javascript when the webapp is in background. (screen shut down or other app in foreground)

I hope I have explained clearly, I'm new in stackoverflow and my english is not so good.
Thanks in advance!

For example, a simple page that you can execute from your mobile browsers and see that interval in not executed like 10 secons, like it would be expected

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        var timeNow = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
        document.body.innerHTML += "<div> " + timeNow + "</div>"    
    }, 10000)
</script>
```

Comment: I honestly don't know much about websockets, but a common problem I've had with them is that sometimes when more than 1 or two people try to connect to the same one, it freaks out. Could this be your problem? Sorry if I'm not of much help. I've made some python programs that host a stream, and it shuts down after two simultaneous connections. Maybe host multiple websockets like a chat app?

Comment: nope,  Websocket closes normally, because android (or chrome, I don't know who is the responsable) kills the connection. I'm actually using a NodeJS websocket in server side, but is the same shit with all servers.